# iPhone: MKMapView and multi-pin

Tags: iphone

I want to show multiple pin in MKMapView for "Sports" category places in my program. Could someone guide me how can i show multi pin in MKMapView for "Sports" places around 20 miles distance from the current location?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create annotation objects and add them to the map. I called them LocalAnnotation.

LocalAnnotation.h:

```
@interface LocationAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

-initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)inCoord;

@end
```

LocalAnnotation.m:

```
#import "locationAnnotation.h"

@implementation LocationAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;

-init
{
    return self;
}

-initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)inCoord
{
    coordinate = inCoord;
    return self;
}
@end
```

Within the method using the map:

```
//erase all annotations
[self.geoMap removeAnnotations:[self.geoMap annotations]];   //geoMap is an MKMapView object.

//Set the pin
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate;
newCoordinate.latitude     = (CLLocationDegrees) [exifGeoLatitudeNumeric doubleValue];  //exifGeoLatitudeNumeric is a NSNumber representing a coordinate in the format +/-23.5435423
newCoordinate.longitude    = (CLLocationDegrees) [exifGeoLongitudeNumeric doubleValue];  //exifGeoLongitudeNumeric is a NSNumber representing a coordinate in the format +/y23.5435423

LocationAnnotation      *newAnnotation  = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:newCoordinate];

[self.geoMap addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much! Can i code for changing pin image(instead of default red one) and can i show the details in small rectangle view when clicking on particular pin?

Comment: Yes you can. I cannot provide you with sample code because I have not yet done it myself. You will find the details properly documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html